# What is the exact difference between the Hardware objects and mailbox in the com communication stack

Tags: autosar, automotive

as of my understanding the hardware object is a kind of buffer used to store the can data in the Can Controller and in the Can Driver will divide data and store in to Hardware transmit handle (HTH) and Hardware receive Handel (HRT). in CANIF will have buffer to refer HTH and HRH and these called as mailbox.

Module name      buffer name
Can Controller - Hardware object
Can Driver     - HTH ,HRH
CANIF          - Mailbox

please correct me if i'am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

From [AUTOSAR_SWS_CANDriver](https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/user_upload/standards/classic/20-11/AUTOSAR_SWS_CANDriver.pdf):

> Hardware Object: A CAN hardware object is defined as a PDU buffer inside the CAN RAM of the CAN hardware unit / CAN controller. A Hardware Object is defined
> as L-PDU buffer inside the CAN RAM of the CAN Hardware Unit.

So basically a hardware object is a mailbox.
In simplest way, each HRH and HTH maps to exactly on hardware object/ mailbox.
However, if SW filtering or pooling is used, this can be different.